# What is the the good way to proceed with LabelEncoder with sklearn to get back the coulples?

Tags: scikit-learn, label-encoding

I have a dataframe with categorical value like city name for instance.

For ML algo., I need then encode the data into numerical value.

I do it like this:

```
df[cat_columns] = df[cat_columns].apply(preprocessing.LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
```

My question is that if I want later to know for instance to what city correspond the encoded value 2.

2 could be for instance "Paris".

For the moment before encoding i do this so that i can get back the info:

```
encoders = {c: preprocessing.LabelEncoder().fit(df[c]) for c in cat_columns}
```

Is it useless? How do you proceed ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LabelEncoder` should only be used to encode your labels, i.e. your target `y`.

To transform categorical columns in the same way you should use [`OrdinalEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html) (however, ordinal encoding might not always be desired - you should look up [`OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) and decide if that's a better fit for your problem).

Let's use an example dataset to explore the correct transformations:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "country": ["France", "France", "Japan", "Netherlands"],
        "city": ["Paris", "Lyon", "Tokyo", "Amsterdam"],
        "population": [13024518, 2323221, 37468000, 2480394]
    }
)
```

Applying `OrdinalEncoder` directly to our full dataset will result in encoding numerical columns as well:

```py
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
>>> enc = OrdinalEncoder()
>>> enc.fit_transform(df)
array([[0., 2., 2.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 3., 3.],
       [2., 0., 1.]])
```

The expected way to perform this transformation is through the use of [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer) to specify the columns we'd like to perform the transformation on:

```py
>>> from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
>>> ct = ColumnTransformer(
...     [("enc", OrdinalEncoder(), ["country", "city"])],
...     remainder="passthrough"
... )
>>> ct.fit_transform(df)
array([[0.0000000e+00, 2.0000000e+00, 1.3024518e+07],
       [0.0000000e+00, 1.0000000e+00, 2.3232210e+06],
       [1.0000000e+00, 3.0000000e+00, 3.7468000e+07],
       [2.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 2.4803940e+06]])
```

We can access the original categories like so (note the indexes in the following array):

```py
>>> ct.named_transformers_["enc"].categories_                
[array(['France', 'Japan', 'Netherlands'], dtype=object), array(['Amsterdam', 'Lyon', 'Paris', 'Tokyo'], dtype=object)]
```

Comment: Yes but how do you get back the numeric values when using LabelEncoder?